How can I create an Azure Public IP address with ".cloudapp.net" DNS suffix?
I'm trying to migrate a couple of Cloud service (classic) to Cloud service (extended support). I've noticed that if I use the Azure portal's built-in "Migrate to ARM" tool then the migration tool creates a Public IP address with a ".cloudapp.net" DNS suffix:
Public IP address with .cloudapp.net suffix
However, if I do the migration manually by following a guide (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/migrate-classic-cloud-service-to-cses-when-sku-is-unsupported/ba-p/4052877) or I just manually create a new Public IP address then I end up with a ".location.cloudapp.azure.com" DNS suffix:
Public IP address with .location.cloudapp.azure.com suffix
Is there a way to achieve what the migration tool does and keep using the ".cloudapp.net" suffix with Cloud service (extended support)?
I'm not really an Azure expert, I tried to compare the resources that the migration tool created and what I created based on the guide but I couldn't figure out what the difference is.
